# Refreshing a page with JavaScript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm currently working on this really simple text based game and to play again, you have to refresh the page. This seems to work in Opera and Chrome, but it's not resetting the page in Firefox. Here is the function I'm using.

```
$(function() {
    $('#play_again').click(function() {
        var answer = confirm ("Reset the game?")
        if (answer) {
        window.location.reload(); 
        }
    });
});
```

I think Firefox is caching the page or something. How could I make this work?

Comment: try history.go(0) as i suggested in my answer ...

Comment: is it helpful for you ????????????

Comment: I ended up using Jakob's answer, but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is something that's hard to do, but you can trick IE's and firefox's cache into thinking it's a new page by adding a random querystring. Can you try something like

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + '?refresh';
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `window.location.href`, I suggest using `window.location.replace`. Why? Because `href` will add a new entry to the browser history. This may not be the behavior you're expecting.

```
window.location.replace( window.location.href )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $('#play_again').click(function () {
        var answer = confirm("Reset the game?")
        if (answer) {
            $("form").each(function () {
                this.reset();
            });
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, he has refreshing issue :)

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. Would it change things if I'm on a local host? Should I just have it redirect it back to the same address, maybe?

Comment: @Sarfraz it could have worked, firefox doesn't clear forms with refresh like chrome does :P

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
document.location=document.location;
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)